# How to return multiple objects in a method with c#?

Tags: c#, object, return

I have a method which retrieves multiple results from my database, I want to return each of these results as an object back to my page however currently it is just returning the last result of the sql command.

Code on my page calling the method:

```
Personen persoon1 = Personen.GetOneItem(int.Parse(TextBox_id.Text));
```

Code of the method:

```
public static Personen GetAllPersonWithID(int id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantConnection"].Connection
String;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Personen where reservering_id=" + id, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Personen Item = new Personen();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Item.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
        Item.menu_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["menu_id"]);
        Item.reservering_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["reservering_id"]);
    }
    con.Close();
    return Item;
}
```

And it only returns the last result in the object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `Personen`? It sounds as if it's already a collection of `Person`, so you have to fill it in the loop.

Comment: you need to return a list of personen, you are just returning a single one

Comment: I'm going to guess you want a `List<Personen>` and would then need to amend the `while (rdr.Read())` content to add to the list for each row.

Comment: Tim, It means People in Dutch. This however isn't really relevant. This method retrieves people's choice of menu and their reservation_number.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you should return a `List<Personen>` or some similar collection type. (Consider declaring the return type as `IList<Personen>` or `IEnumerable<Personen>` and using `List<Personen>` as the implementation type.)

Note that currently you are repeatedly overwriting the properties of a *single* object - you need to fix that too.

For example:

```
...
List<Personen> list = new List<Personen>();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Personen item = new Personen();
    item.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
    item.menu_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["menu_id"]);
    item.reservering_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["reservering_id"]);
    list.Add(item);
}
...
return list;
```

Additionally:

- You should use `using` statements to close your connection, command and reader
- You should use parameterized SQL instead of embedding the parameter in your SQL
- You should follow .NET naming conventions, e.g. `MenuID` instead of `menu_id`
- Consider casting to `int` or using `rdr.GetInt32()` instead of calling `Convert.ToInt32`.
- If `Personen` is already a plural noun, change it to `Person` so that it represents a *single* person

Comment: beaten by 10 seconds :(

Comment: I'd typically prefer returning an `IEnumerable<Personen>` over the List though - just in case you only need the first X items etc.

Comment: @Ian: Do you mean fetching it lazily to start with, using `yield return`? Yes, that's a possibility.

Comment: This is great however how can I access the information in this list from my page? You can't create a list in code behind

Comment: @Gameshadow: Why do you think you can't create a list in the code-behind? (You really haven't given us nearly enough information about what you're doing to help you comprehensively...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yeah using a yield as per my answer, I generally find advising it's better as a lot of people don't understand that you can do it lazily.

Comment: @Ian: Well, it does have some other consequences - such as keeping the connection open for the whole time you're using it, and understanding that even argument validation etc is lazy. Given the level of sophistication of the OP's code at the moment, I'd rather not go into more advanced techniques. (I suspect using LINQ to SQL or EF would actually be better, to be honest...)

Answer (score 0):

You have various options:

a. Return a composite object containing the specific objects you want to return

b. Use out e.g. `void MyMethod(out object obj1, out object obj2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can return `List<Personen>` for your method.
It is recommended to use `using statement` and `command parameter`.

```
public static List<Personen> GetAllPersonWithID(int id)
{
    List<Personen> lstPersonen = new List<Personen>();
    string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantConnection"].ConnectionString;
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Personen where reservering_id=@id";

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {             
       con.Open();
       using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
       {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
          using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
             while (rdr.Read())
             {
                 Personen Item = new Personen();
                 Item.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
                 Item.menu_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["menu_id"]);
                 Item.reservering_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["reservering_id"]);
                 lstPersonen.Add(Item);
             }
          }
       }
    }

    return lstPersonen;
}
```

**How to use the method**:

```
//provide reservering_id here
List<Personen> lstPersonen = GetAllPersonWithID(int.Parse(TextBox_reservering_id.Text)); 

//find a person having id equals to value present in `TextBox_id.Text`
Personen persoon1;
foreach(Personen p in lstPersonen)
{
     //p gets each item present in list
     if(p.id == int.Parse(TextBox_id.Text))
     {  
         persoon1 = p;
         break;
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return a list of persons.

```
List<Personen> items = new List<Personen>();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Personen p = new Personen();
    p.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
    p.menu_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["menu_id"]);
    p.reservering_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["reservering_id"]);
    items.Add(p);
}
return items;
```

Question to think about: Why don't you use a O/R-Mapper?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change you're method signature to return a collection of items, the simplest way to do this is to use an IEnumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<Personen> GetAllPersonWithID(int id){}
```

Next you need to modify you're method to actually return multiple items. In this case you're overwriting the content of the `Item` object frequently, and only returning the last. Change it to read

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Personen Item = new Personen();
    Item.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
    Item.menu_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["menu_id"]);
    Item.reservering_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["reservering_id"]);
    yield return Item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an List for items. On each iteration through rdr add the item into items List. Finally return an List of objects

Comment: An `ArrayList`? Seriously?

Comment: Even with the update this answer seriously pales in comparison to the others.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while-loop, you are resetting the properties of the Item you are returning, so only the last one is remembered. There are several options.

You can return a `List<Personen>` or an `IEnumerable<Personen>` and use yield return.
btw, 'Persoon' would probably be a better name than 'Personen'.

Comment: The problem with Stackoverflow: 5 answers appear before you're finished typing...

Answer (score 0):

Below you will retrive all of the people with the supplied ID. You are however leaving youself vulnerable to SQL injection as you aren't using SQL Command parameters.

```
    public static List<Personen> GetAllPersonWithID(int id)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantConnection"].ConnectionString;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Personen where reservering_id=" + id, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<Personen> rtnList = new List<Personen>();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Personen personen = new Personen();
            personen.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
            personen.menu_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["menu_id"]);
            personen.reservering_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["reservering_id"]);
            rtnList.Add(personen);
        }
        con.Close();
        return rtnList;
    }
```

I hope that helps.